# Using an IEqualityComparer with a LINQ to Entities Except clause

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, iequalitycomparer

I have an entity that I'd like to compare with a subset and determine to select all except the subset.

So, my query looks like this:

```
Products.Except(ProductsToRemove(), new ProductComparer())
```

The `ProductsToRemove()` method returns a `List<Product>` after it performs a few tasks. So in it's simplest form it's the above.

The `ProductComparer()` class looks like this:

```
public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public bool Equals(Product a, Product b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, b)) return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null))
            return false;

        return a.Id == b.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product product)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;
        var hashProductId = product.Id.GetHashCode();
        return hashProductId;
    }
}
```

However, I continually receive the following exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[UnitedOne.Data.Sql.Product]
>   Except[Product](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[UnitedOne.Data.Sql.Product],
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[UnitedOne.Data.Sql.Product],
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[UnitedOne.Data.Sql.Product])'
>   method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linq to Entities isn't actually executing your query, it is *interpreting* your code, converting it to TSQL, then executing that on the server.

Under the covers, it is coded with the knowledge of how operators and common functions operate and how those relate to TSQL.  The problem is that the developers of L2E have no idea how exactly you are implementing IEqualityComparer.  Therefore they cannot figure out that when you say `Class A == Class B` you mean (for example) `"Where Person.FirstName == FirstName AND Person.LastName == LastName"`.

So, when the L2E interpreter hits a method it doesn't recognize, it throws this exception.

There are two ways you can work around this.  First, develop a `Where()` that satisfies your equality requirements but that doesn't rely on any custom method.  In other words, test for equality of properties of the instance rather than an `Equals` method defined on the class.

Second, you can trigger the execution of the query and then do your comparisons in memory. For instance:

```
var notThisItem = new Item{Id = "HurrDurr"};
var items = Db.Items.ToArray(); // Sql query executed here
var except = items.Except(notThisItem); // performed in memory
```

Obviously this will bring much more data across the wire and be more memory intensive.  The first option is usually the best.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In this case, we're only talking less than 100 rows so I think the second option isn't that bad. I may cache the results just to speed up future seek. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `ToArray` you can also use `AsEnumerable` which will also execute it in memory but doesn''t need to load everything from db into memory before it starts processing it. That can make a huge difference.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to convert the `Except` call with your custom `IEqualityComparer` into Entity SQL.

Obviously, your class cannot be converted into SQL.

You need to write `Products.AsEnumerable().Except(ProductsToRemove(), new ProductComparer())` to force it to execute on the client.  Note that this will download all of the products from the server.

---

By the way, your `ProductComparer` class should be a singleton, like this:

```
public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product> {
    private ProductComparer() { }
    public static ProductComparer Instance = new ProductComparer();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey Slaks, could you elaborate on using IEqualityComparer as singleton? Performance-wise or any other reason? Because I am having trouble finding samples with IEqualityComparer as singleton, even in MSDN documentation.

Comment: @Mare: Since there is no difference between individual instances, there's no point in having more than one instance.

Answer (score 3):

The `IEqualityComparer<T>` can only be executed locally, it can't be translated to a SQL command, hence the error