# Distinct by part of the string in linq

Tags: regex, linq, linq-to-objects

Given this collection:

```
var list = new [] {
    "1.one",
    "2. two",
    "no number",
    "2.duplicate",
    "300. three hundred",
    "4-ignore this"};
```

How can I get subset of items that start with a number followed by a dot (**regex `@"^\d+(?=\.)"`**) with **distinct** numbers? That is:

```
{"1.one", "2. two", "300. three hundred"}
```

**UPDATE:**

My attempt on this was to use an `IEqualityComparer` to pass to the `Distinct` method. I borrowed this [GenericCompare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23623976/450913) class and tried the following code to no avail:

```
var pattern = @"^\d+(?=\.)";
var comparer = new GenericCompare<string>(s => Regex.Match(s, pattern).Value);
list.Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, pattern)).Distinct(comparer);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you fancy an approach with Linq, you can try adding a named capture group to the regex, then filter the items that match the regex, group by the captured number and finally get only the first string for each number. I like the readability of the solution but I wouldn´t be surprised if there is a more efficient way of eliminating the duplicates, let´s see if somebody else comes with a different approach.

Something like this:

```
list.Where(s => regex.IsMatch(s))
    .GroupBy(s => regex.Match(s).Groups["num"].Value)
    .Select(g => g.First())
```

You can give it a try with this sample:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?<num>\d+)\.", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new [] {
            "1.one",
            "2. two",
            "no number",
            "2.duplicate",
            "300. three hundred",
            "4-ignore this"
        };

        var distinctWithNumbers = list.Where(s => regex.IsMatch(s))
                                      .GroupBy(s => regex.Match(s).Groups["num"].Value)
                                      .Select(g => g.First());

        distinctWithNumbers.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }       
}
```

You can try the approach it in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ywr8G)

As pointed by @orad in the comments, there is a Linq extension [`DistinctBy()`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) in MoreLinq that could be used instead of grouping and then getting the first item in the group to eliminate the duplicates:

```
var distinctWithNumbers = list.Where(s => regex.IsMatch(s))
                              .DistinctBy(s => regex.Match(s).Groups["num"].Value);
```

Try it in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/znmT0V)

**EDIT**

If you want to use your comparer, you need to implement the `GetHashCode` so it uses the expression as well:

```
public int GetHashCode(T obj)
{
    return _expr.Invoke(obj).GetHashCode();
}
```

Then you can use the comparer with a lambda function that takes a string and gets the number using the regex:

```
var comparer = new GenericCompare<string>(s => regex.Match(s).Groups["num"].Value);
var distinctWithNumbers = list.Where(s => regex.IsMatch(s)).Distinct(comparer);
```

I have created another [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uu8FKn) with this approach.

**Using lookahead regex**

You can use any of these 2 approaches with the regex `@"^\d+(?=\.)"`.

Just change the lambda expressions getting the "num" group `s => regex.Match(s).Groups["num"].Value` with a expression that gets the regex match `s => regex.Match(s).Value`

Updated [fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iRlpP7).

Comment: Great, this seems to work. I will mark it as answer if nothing better comes. Also please see my update on using a comparer. Thanks.

Comment: Minor note, instead of regex groups you could use regex lookahead like `@"^\d+(?=\.)"` so that only number part is matched.

Comment: Simpler solution: use `DistinctBy` from MoreLINQ. See Jon Skeet's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1300116/450913).

Comment: I came up with a solution that does not run the regex twice on the collection by using a Dictionary. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25516465/450913).

Comment: Nice, using the `DistinctBy` extension the code is really nice and simple. I guess you may want to measure the different approaches and then decide whether to go for performance or readability. (Also, you could avoid the parsing in your solution, using the match as the key, an empty string when no match)

Answer (score 1):

(I could mark this as answer too)

This solution works without duplicate regex runs:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d+(?=\.)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
list.Select(i => {
    var m = regex.Match(i);
    return new KeyValuePair<int, string>( m.Success ? Int32.Parse(m.Value) : -1, i );
})
.Where(i => i.Key > -1)
.GroupBy(i => i.Key)
.Select(g => g.First().Value);
```

Run it in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oGZRwP).

Comment: Like @daniel-j-g said, parsing can be avoided here, using the match as the key, an empty string when no match.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is good enough.

You can also use LINQ query syntax to avoid regex re-runs with the help of `let` keyword as follows:

```
var result =
        from kvp in
        (
            from s in source
            let m = regex.Match(s)
            where m.Success
            select new KeyValuePair<int, string>(int.Parse(m.Value), s)
        )
        group kvp by kvp.Key into gr
        select new string(gr.First().Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
List<string> c = new List<string>()
{
    "1.one",
    "2. two",
    "no number",
    "2.duplicate",
    "300. three hundred",
    "4-ignore this"
};

c.Where(i =>
{
    var match = Regex.Match(i, @"^\d+(?=\.)");
    return match.Success;
});
```

Comment: This will also include `"2.duplicate"`. The key in my question is how to get **Distinct** numbers.