# What is the best way to compare two list of complex object in c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, compare, points

Hello friends I want to create a method that get two list of point (object that I'm created) and return 3 list that include:

1. Points that exist in the first and the second list.
2. Points that exist in the first list and not exist in the second list.
3. Points that not exist in the first and exist in the second list.

What is the best wat to do that?

Point.cs:

```
Public class Point {public int X; public int Y}
```

Comment: If you need information on set operation - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Set-Operators-374f34fe. More similar answers can be found https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+items+exist+both+list.

Comment: Hope this question can answer your query. [Get list of matching objects from 3 different lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444334/get-list-of-matching-objects-from-3-different-lists)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a `IEqualityComparer<Point>`. Then use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Linq methods to achieve what you want.

1. var result = points1.Intersect(points2, yourComparer);
2. var result = points1.Except(points2, yourComparer);
3. var result = points2.Except(points1, yourComparer);

where points1 and points2 are your list of points.

To implement IEqualityComparer, [refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694508/how-to-use-the-iequalitycomparer) as a start.

Comment: 1. What is yourComparer? 2. How I convert this to List?

Comment: @Lol  1.yourComparer is the instance of the `IEqualityComparer<Point>` which you'll be creating (How to do that is the last part of my answer). 2. `var myList = points1.Intersect(points2, yourComparer).ToList();`. Just call `ToList()` in the end.

Comment: Ok, Another quastion: I'm understand that Linq compare between the HashCode so I need that the method GetHash code return X value and Y value. How I do that?

Comment: @Lol This will help to understand [how to implement GetHashCode method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) also [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/)

Comment: I still do not understand why I need to implement the Equal and the HashCode? Which function is used to make the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple things.

First use `System.Drawing.Point` struct instead of your own class and you will be able to the comparison as well.

Second, If you have to create your own class then override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class.

Comment: I'm understand that Linq compare between the HashCode so I need that the method GetHash code return X value and Y value. How I do that?