# Separate collection on 2 different NEW collections

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have collection of elements and one additional small collection as filter.

I need to separate it on 2 new collections by some filter. In my case it is first collection that contains some elements and another that doesn't.

There aren't items that doesn't exists out of that 2 new collections.

I did it like :

```
var collection1= baseCollection.Where(r => filterCollection.Contains(r.Property)).ToList();
var collection2= baseCollection.Where(r => !filterCollection.Contains(r.Property)).ToList();
```

But is there another, I hope more elegant way, to separate collection? 
For me it looks like "I repeat myself", use almost the same code 2 times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You can create a variable for the function - this way you will not "repeat yourself" *(wouldn't use in this case, there are better options below, but still an option)*:

   ```
   Func<YourClass,bool> filtering = (r) => filterCollection.Contains(r.Property);

   var collection1 = baseCollection.Where(r => filtering(r));
   var collection2 = baseCollection.Where(r => !filtering(r));
   ```
2. If your type of the collection overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you can use `Except`:

   ```
   var collection1 = baseCollection.Where(r => filterCollection.Contains(r.Property));
   var collection2 = baseCollection.Except(collection1);
   ```
3. Using `Except` with a given [`IEqualityComparer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694508/how-to-use-the-iequalitycomparer) *(Check also first comment for guidlines)*:

   ```
   public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<YourClass>
   {
       public bool Equals(YourClass x, YourClass y)
       {
           // Your implementation
       }

       public int GetHashCode(YourClass obj)
       {
           // Your implementation
       }
   }

   var collection1 = baseCollection.Where(r => filterCollection.Contains(r.Property));
   var collection2 = baseCollection.Except(collection1, new Comparer());
   ```
4. You can also use `GroupBy` *(probably less good performance wise)*:

   ```
   var result baseCollection.GroupBy(r => filterCollection.Contains(r.Property))
                            .ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.ToList());

   var collection1 = result[true];
   var collection2 = result[false];
   ```
5. Otherwise another way will just to use a loop:

   ```
   List<YourType> collection1 = new List<YourType>();
   List<YourType> collection2 = new List<YourType>();
   foreach(var item in baseCollection)
   {
       if(filterCollection.Contains(item.Property))
       {
           collection1.Add(item);
       }
       else
       {
           collection2.Add(item);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Is it faster than 2 times `Where` ?

Comment: @demo - about performance I'm not sure. One must check. Probably the fastest is option 3 - *o(n) for the baseCollection part (not including the contains because all solutions use it)*.

Comment: `Except` is faster than `Where` since it's using a set based approach to filter. Instead of overriding `Equals` + `GetHashCode` you could also use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.