# Remove and get duplicates in a list in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which consists of the following properties:

```
public class Category 
{    
   public int RecordId { get; set;}
   public string Category { get; set;}
   public Data DataObj { get; set;}
}
```

My list is defined as `List<Category>` categories.

The data class holds the following properties:

```
{
   Id: 1,
   Name: "Smith",
   Input: "7,8",
   Output: "Output1",
   CreatedBy: "swallac",
   CreatedON: "12/01/2018"
},
{
   Id: 3,
   Name: "Austin",
   Input: "9,10",
   Output: "Output1",
   CreatedBy: "amanda",
   CreatedON: "12/03/2018"
},
{
   Id: 2,
   Name: "Austin",
   Input: "9,10",
   Output: "Output1",
   CreatedBy: "amanda",
   CreatedON: "12/03/2018"
}
```

How can I get the duplicate item in the Data object?

I have tried the following but does not seem to return me the correct results.

```
 var categoriesFiltered = categories.Select(g => g.DataObj);

 var duplicateDataa = categoriesFiltered.GroupBy(x => x)
                                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                     .Select(y => y.Key);
```

Comment: [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0) is your friend. Implement `IEquatable<T>` in your `Category` class.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen `Distinct()` would not find the duplicate, OP question is "_How can I get the duplicate item in the Data object?_"

Comment: @Cleptus: Then there's two questions. Headline says `Remove duplicates in a list in C#`.

Comment: Indeed, a bit unclear the question

Comment: @Cleptus I want to get the duplicate items first and then remove them.

Comment: There is no duplicate items in your question. The Ids are different. What is the exact criteria for detecting the duplicate items?

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate? All properties being equal other than `Id`?

Comment: @Bizhan: The properties Name, input output

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yes you got it right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group By Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: OK, then your problem then boils down to do a grouping with those common properties, I have flagged your question as duplicated, check the link and the asnwer given in that related/duplicated question. It should help you.

Comment: @Cleptus How to remove the duplicate items?

Comment: What if the common properties are generic? How do I do the filtering?

Comment: Tow ways: a) You could do a grouping and retrieve the common properties and the MIN(Id). Then remove all items that have those common properties and their Id is not the Min(id). The option b) Follow Sani Singh's comment [or Bizhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67314090/2265446)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Equality Comparer:

```
    class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Category>
    {
        public bool Equals(Category? x, Category? y)
        {
            return x?.DataObj.Name == y?.DataObj.Input &&
                   x?.DataObj.Input == y?.DataObj.Input &&
                   x?.DataObj.Output == y?.DataObj.Output;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Category obj)
        {
            return obj.DataObj.Name.GetHashCode() +
                   obj.DataObj.Input.GetHashCode() +
                   obj.DataObj.Output.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then use that comparer to make a distinction between your items:

```
 var distinctList = categoriesFiltered.Distinct(new MyComparer());
```

Alternatively you can implement `IEquatable<T>` on any class that needs to be compared in an arbitrary way:

```
    public class Category : IEquatable<Category>
    {
        public int RecordId { get; set;}
        public string Category { get; set;}
        public Data DataObj { get; set;}

        public bool Equals(Category? other)
        {
            return DataObj.Equals(other?.DataObj);
        }
    }
    public class Data : IEquatable<Data>
    {
        ...
        public bool Equals(Data? other)
        {
            return Name.Equals(other?.Name) && Input.Equals(other?.Input) && ...;
        }
    }
```

Then let C# use them:

```
 var distinctList = categoriesFiltered.Distinct();
```

If you want to know which items are removed as duplicate you can use `Except`:

```
 duplicates = categoriesFiltered.Except(distinctList);
```

Comment: What if the the `Category` is of type `T`? How can I do that with varying properties knowing that I will have only one property in common, `Id`?

Comment: I want to exclude the `Id` property when doing the comparison though. Please help.

Comment: @Chatwa the original question was actually two different questions with little information provided which can find the complete answer here. But it's difficult to understand your question if you can't describe it properly. So what you said earlier about comparing Name, Input and Output of two `Category` objects was actually not true, and you want to use reflection to search any two objects for all their properties and then what.. exclude the one with the name equal to "Id"? Is this your actual question? I wouldn't go down the reflection path as it's usually too slow.

Comment: @Chatwa If you need to compare any two objects with arbitrary comparison logic it's best to just implement IEquatable<T> on all your classes and implement your custom comparison logic there. as JonasH mentioned

Comment: I am bit confused. Could you please help about the implementation?

Comment: Maybe something similar like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23623976/15760192? Just to avoid the reflection

Answer (score 1):

You are probably lacking a equalitycomparer.

Since `Category` is a class without an equals method it will default to reference equality. There are several ways to define equality of objects.

1. Create a new class, implementing `IEqualityComparer<Category>`, use this class as input to your `Distinct` call. This allow multiple different ways to compare the same type.
2. Let `Category` Implement `IEquatable<Category>`
3. Override `Equals(object)` method.

Comment: How can I implement it in a generic way? I want to exclude the `Id` property though.

Comment: You can make a `KeyEqualityComparer` that takes a `Func< T, TKey>` that selects a property to compare. In this case you might be able to create one that takes a `Func<T, string[]> and compares all the strings for equality. But there is a risk that the generic solution will end up much more complicated than just a regular implementation, so you might want to just go with the example Bizhan provided.

Comment: I want to compare all properties except the `Id` one.

Comment: Maybe something similar like this?

Comment: @Chatwa There is no magic "compare everything except the Id" function. You could perhaps write something like that using reflection, but it would be horribly complicated and probably also fragile. Assuming you are referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694508/how-to-use-the-iequalitycomparer/23623976#23623976) it is the same concept as "`KeyEqualityComparer`", but it will not work for your case since you have several properties to compare.