# XUnit Mocking Passing and Asserting a Collection

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

New to XUnit and attempting to test the following method but test is failing.
I believe the reason is that a new instance of the data is created when the assert is called.
So even thought the results are the same the object reference is not.

When a new record is added to the collection, it is supposed to returned the same record added.

**Employee Data Class:**

```
    public class EmployeeData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

    }
```

**Method to test:**

```
        public List<EmployeeData> Add(List<EmployeeData> employees)
        {

            foreach(var employee in employees)
            {
                data.Add(new EmployeeData() { Id = newId(), 
                        FirstName = employee.FirstName, LastName = employee.LastName, 
                        Title = employee.Title });
            }

            return data;
        }
```

**Test Method:**

```
        [Fact]
        public void Add()
        {
            // Arrange
            var data = new List<EmployeeData>();

            data.Add(new EmployeeData() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Adams", LastName = "John", Title = "Fireman" });

            // Mocking the employee class constructor arguments.
            var mockLogging = new Mock<ILogger<DataService>>();
            var mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
            var sut = new Employee(mockLogging.Object, mockConfig.Object);

            var result = sut.Add(data);

            // Assert should return the exact data inputted
            Assert.Equal(result, data);
        }
```

**Test Result:**

```
  Message: 
Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: List<EmployeeData> [EmployeeData { FirstName = "Adams", Id = 1, LastName = "John", Title = "Fireman" }]
Actual:   List<EmployeeData> [EmployeeData { FirstName = "Adams", Id = 1, LastName = "John", Title = "Fireman" }]
```

Comment: Can you use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()`?

Comment: @SteveWong This does not work for XUnit.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in your `EmployeeData` class?

Comment: I do not see the data variable to be declared in the Add method?

Comment: The result is true. Because values are the same but their references are different from each other.  You can try this
Enumerable.SequenceEqual(list1, list2) -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does it mean that `EmployeeData` equals `EmployeeData`?
You can override `Equals` methods in the `EmployeeData` class.

```
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return this.FirstName == ((EmployeeData)obj).FirstName;
        }
```

The second option is to pass `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the `Equal` method.

```
    public class GenericCompare<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
    {
        private Func<T, object> _expr { get; set; }
        public GenericCompare(Func<T, object> expr)
        {
            this._expr = expr;
        }
        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            var first = _expr.Invoke(x);
            var sec = _expr.Invoke(y);
            if (first != null && first.Equals(sec))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

And use it:

```
Assert.Equal<EmployeeData>(result, data, new GenericCompare<EmployeeData>(x => x.Id));
```

Copy pasted `GenericCompare` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23623976/6629020